# Client-side custom data caching

Tags: lightning, data, locker-service, caching

Does anybody knows how to implement client-side data caching under locker service (as it disables default browser cache call from js)?

The use case is as follows:
I have community page built with several components on it.
These components uses the same set of data to some extent, so I want to fetch this data once, and store it somewhere (preferable in some map/wrapper object) so components wouldn't have to retrieve them on every single init.

I'll appreciate any help and ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's best to work with the framework, so I suggest that you have a read about the caching that Lightning offers

- Storable actions
- Lightning Data Service
- Custom cache

See: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/04/lightning-components-performance-best-practices.html#data_caching